# panic: http: multiple registrations for /debug/requests

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, vendor

I vendored two projects in my go project. And I successfully compiled my project. When I ran my project, it reported error `"panic: http: multiple registrations for /debug/requests"`. The detailed errors is shown below.

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
net/http.(*ServeMux).Handle(0x19ae000, 0x126bb20, 0xf, 0x1964540, 0x1297d90)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2270 +0x627
net/http.(*ServeMux).HandleFunc(0x19ae000, 0x126bb20, 0xf, 0x1297d90)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2302 +0x55
net/http.HandleFunc(0x126bb20, 0xf, 0x1297d90)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2314 +0x4b
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace.init.0()
/home/chalex/ibm/src/github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace/trace.go:115 +0x42
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace.init()
<autogenerated>:1 +0x1cd
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.init()
<autogenerated>:1 +0x82
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/third_party/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer.init()
<autogenerated>:1 +0x6f
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/api/apitxn.init()
<autogenerated>:1 +0x44
github.own.com/chalex/testfabric/chaincode/client.init()
<autogenerated>:1 +0x49
main.init()
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it? I guess it's because the two projects I imported both listen on `/debug/requests`?

Comment: Your guess i right. Must change code.

Comment: This is why it's dangerous for libraries to do this sort of thing in `init` functions. They should only register handlers when you explicitly tell them to.

Comment: Thank you. @Volker @Adrian. I found the reason. It's because of the `golang.org/x/net/trace` project. In it's `init()` function, they handle the `debug/request` with hard code. So if two projects both import that library, then there is a conflict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the reason. It's because of the `golang.org/x/net/trace` project. In it's `init()` function, they handle the `debug/request` with hard code. So if two projects both import that library, then there is a conflict.

Comment: The cause of issue is as explained by @chalex above. The temporary fix for me was to comment out the ```init()``` method inside the ```$GOPATH/pkg/mod/<mypackage>/Godeps/_/x/net/trace/trace.go```

Answer (score 5):

More than one project used `golang.org/x/net/trace`, and some project saved `golang.org/x/net/trace` in its `vendor` directory, so that is causing the conflict. Fix the conflict by deleting others and only leaving one,then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to figure out WHAT package is responsible for the "double" vendoring?